# Como usar um script do SQLServer para criar um banco de dados no SQLite?

Tags: android, sqlite

Eu tenho um script gerado do SQL Server ela contém várias tabelas e views, eu pretendo transportar esta base de dados para o meu SQLite Android.

**Como faço para executar o script no SQLite no Android ?**

Comment: Tem de ser mais especifico na dificuldade que tem. De qualquer forma possa adiantar que é possível o script(SQL) não ser compatível com o SQLite,

Comment: Tem um jeito de transportar a minha base de dados (SQL) para uma base de dados interna do Android?

Comment: Cara da uma pesquisada no google...

Comment: Você sabe criar uma base de dados no SQLite via SQLiteOpenHelper?

Comment: Sim, sei criar.

Answer (score 3):

Siga os seguintes passos:

- No lado do SQLServer gere o *script* de criação.
- Altere o *script* de forma a ser compatível com o SQLite.
- Derive de SQLiteOpenHelper e use o *script* da mesma forma que faz quando cria qualquer outro banco, usando `db.execSQL()`.

Nota: `db.execSQL()` só executa um comando SQL de cada vez. Terá obter cada uma dos comandos SQL existentes no *script* e executá-los um a um, qualquer coisa assim:

```
StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer( script, ";", false);

while (tokenizer.hasMoreTokens())
{
    db.execSQL(tokenizer.nextToken());
}
```